# Doctrine2 ManyToMany relation using PostgreSQL: "SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: the relation does not exist"

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

When I make an INNER JOIN between two entities (connected by a **ManyToMany** relationship) doctrine says that cannot find the relation *machine_table_for_base_model*: `SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: the relation "machine_table_for_base_model"  does not exist`. Why this happens?

I have an [associative table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29) defined as follows:

```
 <!-- language: lang-sql -->

CREATE TABLE machine_table_for_base_model ( 
    id_machine_table integer NOT NULL, 
    id_base_model integer NOT NULL, 
); 

 ALTER TABLE ONLY machine_table_for_base_model 
     ADD CONSTRAINT machine_table_for_base_model_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id_machine_table, id_base_model); 

 ALTER TABLE ONLY machine_table_for_base_model 
     ADD CONSTRAINT machine_table_for_base_model_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (id_machine_table) REFERENCES machine_table(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED; 

 ALTER TABLE ONLY machine_table_for_base_model 
     ADD CONSTRAINT machine_table_for_base_model_ibfk_2 FOREIGN KEY (id_base_model) REFERENCES base_model(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

When I execute a doctrine mapping of the associated tables I have something like that:

```
Package\MyBundle\Entity\MachineTable:
    type: entity
    schema: techguide
    table: machine_table
    indexes:
        IDX_8386B61E3C5569AA:
            columns:
                - edit_user
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            nullable: false
            options:
                unsigned: false
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: SEQUENCE
    fields:
        description:
            type: string
            nullable: false
            length: 200
            options:
                fixed: false
        labelsDimensions:
            type: text
            nullable: false
            length: null
            options:
                fixed: false
            column: labels_dimensions
        editDate:
            type: datetime
            nullable: false
            options:
                default: now
            column: edit_date
    manyToOne:
        editUser:
            targetEntity: Package\SupportBundle\Entity\Account
            cascade: {  }
            fetch: LAZY
            mappedBy: null
            inversedBy: null
            joinColumns:
                edit_user:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            orphanRemoval: false
    manyToMany:
        idBaseModel:
            targetEntity: BaseModel
            cascade: {  }
            fetch: LAZY
            mappedBy: null
            inversedBy: idMachineTable
            joinTable:
                name: machine_table_for_base_model
                joinColumns:
                    -
                        name: id_machine_table
                        referencedColumnName: id
                inverseJoinColumns:
                    -
                        name: id_base_model
                        referencedColumnName: id
            orderBy: null
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I found a solution to this problem. You need to edit (**manually**) the `joinTable` name on the ORM configuration, which in my case is a Yaml file, adding the Postgres schema the associative table belongs to:

**<kbd>Entity.orm.yml</kbd>**

```
manyToMany:
    idBaseModel:
        targetEntity: BaseModel
        cascade: {  }
        fetch: LAZY
        mappedBy: null
        inversedBy: idMachineTable
        joinTable:
            name: <NAME_OF_YOUR_SCHEMA>.<NAME_OF_THE_TABLE>
            joinColumns:
                -
                    name: id_machine_table
                    referencedColumnName: id
            inverseJoinColumns:
                -
                    name: id_base_model
                    referencedColumnName: id
        orderBy: null
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```